# The radical of the product of two ideals is the intersection of the radicals of the ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring (not sure if "Noetherianness" is needed). I'm trying to show that $r(IJ)=r(I)\cap r(J)$ ($r$ for radical).

One direction looks easy. If $x\in r(IJ)$, then for some $k$, $x^k\in IJ$. Since $IJ\subset I\cap J$, $x^k\in I\cap J$, so $x\in r(I)\cap r(J)$.

The other direction is not clear to me. Let $x\in r(I)\cap r(J)$. Then $x^n\in I, x^m\in J$. So $x^{\max(n,m)}\in I\cap J$. If $I+J=R$, then $I\cap J\subset IJ$, and I would be able to conclude that $x\in r(IJ)$. But it need not be the casse that $I+J=R$. How do I proceed then?

Comment: If $x^n\in I$ and $x^m\in J$, then $x^{n+m}\in IJ$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oh well apparently I didn't bother to consider $x^nx^m=x^{n+m}$...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What can you say about $x^m\times x^n$?